# Twitter4j cache ResponseList<?>

Tags: android, json, caching, twitter4j, jtwitter

I have been making an android app for quite a few weeks and almost have it near release but I have a problem. I need to be able to cache responselists from twitter such as friends and search results using twitter4j. I know I can get the raw Json for the responselist using DataObjectFactory.getRawJSON() which I can cache but there is no way that I can find to turn this back into a responselist??

I also tried using gson to cache the results but that says that User (responselist) is not serialisable and crashes and I cannot edit User as it is in a .jar.

I would prefer to use the rawJson so is there a way to convert that back to a responselist? I know I can get the raw json of a user and turn it back into a user so surely there must be a way to do it with a whole responselist and not just each seperate user or whatever kind of responselist you are using?

Any help is appreciated, I really don't want to start using databases or anything to cache the twitter results and think there must be a way to do what I am asking to do?